# How to find the list with most elements in the items of a dict?

Tags: python

Say that I have

```
function(Dict[str, List[str]] -> List[str]
```

how could I return a list that contains the str in the Dict with most elements in the list?

```
function({'a':['1','2'], 'b':['1'], 'c':['1', '2']})

['a', 'c']
```

The function should be able to still return the str even if more than one str has the most elements in the list just like the above example. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the max length first, then loop over the elements to filter those that have the max length:

```py
def get_max(d):
    max_len = max(map(len,d.values()))
    return [k for k,v in d.items() if len(v)==max_len]

get_max({'a':['1','2'], 'b':['1'], 'c':['1', '2']})
# ['a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
def fun(d):
    current, res = 0, []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if len(v) > current:
            res = [k]
            current = len(v)
        elif len(v) == current:
            res.append(k)
            current = len(v)
    return res


final = fun({"a": ['1', '2'], "b": ['1'], "c": ['1', '2']})
print(final)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: :D I hesitated to add such an algo as complement (I was lazy), glad you did ;)

Comment: NB. for the beginner reading this, the above algorithm is sometimes more efficient as it requires to read only once the input, sometimes less efficient as it requires to append the values and rewrite the output. The threshold for which it is more or less efficient depends on the size of the input and the number of final elements that end up selected. (e.g, 30% faster on the provided example, twice slower on `{i: 'abc' for i in range(10000)}`)

Answer (score 0):

Your function will look like this:

```
def dict_to_max_list(mydict):
    for item in mydict.items():
        mydict[item[0]] = len(item[1])
    all_values = mydict.values()
    max_value = max(all_values)

    # Using list comprehension
    mylist = [x[0] for x in mydict.items() if x[1] == max_value]
    return mylist
```

The above function accepts a dict. Iterates through your dict and calculate the length of each list in your dict. And then returns list with maximum value using list comprehension.

```
d1 = {'a':['1','2'], 'b':['1'], 'c':['1', '2']}
list1 = dict_to_max_list(d1)
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(dict_list: dict):
    #set the max length to 0
    greatest_length = 0
    lists_with_greatest_length = []

    #for each list if the length is greater than greatest_length 
    #we overwrite lists_with_greatest_length with the new list and take its length as the largest.
    for (key, liste) in zip(dictt.keys(), dictt.values()):
        if len(liste) > greatest_length:
           greatest_length = len(liste)
           lists_with_greatest_length = [key]

        elif len(liste) == greatest_length:
           lists_with_greatest_length.append(key)

    return lists_with_greatest_length
```